# How to undersample a dataframe by 40%?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset, sampling

I have a dataset of csv file which I converted into a dataframe. This is a two class dataset, 0 and 1. The dataset is quite imbalanced as most of the instances belong to class 1. I am trying to randomly undersample or remove 30-40% of the instances from the majority class. I am not sure how to do it. I have looked for online resources but all of them do undersampling or oversampling to 50-50%.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, [DataFrame.sample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) seems to be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

1. Try splitting the df into 2, one with the zeros (df0) and one with the ones (df1).
2. Downsample the ones dataframe using df1=df1.sample(frac=0.6).
3. Then rejoin the 2 dataframes, as in df = pd.concat([df0, df1])